# How can I change how often an object bounces, without decreasing its x velocity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm relatively new to programming. I'm working on a 2D platformer, and I'm trying to get an object to bounce at a consistent height, with a fairly fast movement speed, with little space between the bounces. I've got the first two, but am having some trouble with the last part.

Basically, I want the object to hit the ground more often than it does, but so far, the only way I have achieved that is by decreasing the movement speed, which makes it move too slowly.

Here's some code to show what I'm doing (I've cut out everything not relevant to the actual bouncing):

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 12.0f;
    [SerializeField] float bounce = 180.0f;

    Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    CircleCollider2D myCollider;

    void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        myCollider = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
        Bounce();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
    }

    private void Bounce()
    {
        if (!myCollider.IsTouchingLayers(LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"))) { return; }

        myRigidbody.AddForce(Vector2.up * bounce);
    }
}
```

Here's an image to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

Example 1 in that image is the result I currently have, while Example 2 is the result I want.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve the result of Example 2, without decreasing the movement speed? Thanks.

Comment: Increase the bouncing motion's speed? Decrease the bounce height? Change the physics scale?

Comment: You're limited to those parameters that determine the behavior. You'll have to give somewhere else if you don't want to reduce the movement speed.

Comment: If don't want it to move slower then it sounds like the option you want it "bounce faster" .. In general: why do you call `Move` in `LateUpdate` at all? once the velocity for x is set why set it again? And I guess to make it bounce faster you could increase the gravity and the amount of force you add at the same time so it results in the same bounce height but faster movement maybe

Comment: derHugo - Thanks! Increasing both the gravity scale and the bounce height worked perfectly. Also, yeah, you're right about setting the velocity multiple times. I guess I got used to doing it that way for objects where the velocity might change (like the player), but for something like this, yeah, I only need to set it once. Again, thanks.